# Como prever tamanho do menu para não quebrar

Tags: css

Tenho um menu que é gerenciável. O cliente colocou muitos itens na *li* com isso o menu jogou alguns itens para baixo, sobrepondo o banner que há abaixo.
Tem como eu prever o tamanho do menu? Talvez na *ul* mesmo. Ai quando o número de *li* for muito muito grande, ele aumenta a **height** e não joga os itens sobrepondo o banner.

```css
header nav {
  background: #ff0000;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: block;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
}

header nav>.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

header nav>.wrap>ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

header nav>.wrap>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

header nav>.wrap>ul>li:first-child {
  border: 0;
}

header nav>.wrap>ul>li>a {
  font-style: italic!important;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font: 800 13px/70px 'Nunito', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 35px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.45s ease;
  height: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header nav>.wrap>ul>li>a>span {
  /*background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: block; height: 50px;*/
}

header nav>.wrap>ul>li:hover>a {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

header nav ul li .submenu {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #BD1A20;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: none;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  z-index: 2000;
}

header nav ul li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}

header nav ul li .submenu>ul {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

header nav ul li .submenu>ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
  -moz-column-gap: 40px;
  column-gap: 40px;
}

header nav ul li .submenu>ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #211f20;
  font: 500 11px/22px 'Nunito', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header nav ul li .submenu>ul li a:hover {
  color: #BD1A20;
}

header nav ul li .submenu>ul li strong a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font: 800 10px/20px 'Nunito', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header nav ul li .submenu .submenu-img {
  float: right;
  width: 35%;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}

header nav ul li .submenu .submenu-img img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-mobile {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="wrap cf">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/">
            <span style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/categorias/);"></span>
          </a>


        </li>
        <li class="list-cat">
          <a href="/ar-condicionado">
            <span style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/categorias/);"></span> Ar Condicionado </a>

          <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/ar-condicionado-comando-do-ar-condicionado">Comando Do Ar Condicionado</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/ar-condicionado-compressor-ar-condicionado">Compressor Ar Condicionado</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/ar-condicionado-condensador-ar-condicionado">Condensador Ar Condicionado</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="list-cat">
          <a href="/eletricas">
            <span style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/categorias/);"></span> Elétricas </a>

          <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/eletricas-alternador">Alternador</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/eletricas-bomba-de-combustivel">Bomba de combustivel</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/eletricas-chave-de-seta">Chave de seta</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/eletricas-chicote">Chicote</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/eletricas-motor-de-arranque">Motor de arranque</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/eletricas-painel-de-intrumento">Painel de intrumento</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="list-cat">
          <a href="/freios">
            <span style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/categorias/);"></span> Freios </a>

          <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/freios-cilindro-mestre">Cilindro mestre</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/freios-disco">Disco</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/freios-hidrovaco">Hidrovaco</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/freios-pinsa">Pinsa</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="list-cat">
          <a href="/iluminalcao">
            <span style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/categorias/);"></span> iluminalçao </a>

          <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/ilumicao-farol">Farol</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/ilumicao-lanterna">Lanterna</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="list-cat">
          <a href="/lataria">
            <span style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/categorias/);"></span> Lataria </a>

          <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/lataria-capo">capo</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/lataria-lateral">Lateral</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/lataria-mine-frente">Mine frente</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/lataria-parachoque">Parachoque</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/lataria-paralama">Paralama</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/lataria-portas">Portas</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/lataria-tampa-traseira">Tampa traseira</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="list-cat">
          <a href="/motor">
            <span style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/categorias/);"></span> Motor </a>

          <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/motor-biela">Biela</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/motor-cabecote">Cabeçote</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/motor-motor-completo">Motor completo</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/motor-pistao">Pistao</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/motor-radiador">Radiador</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/motor-tbi">TBI</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/motor-virabrequin">Virabrequin</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="list-cat">
          <a href="/suspensao">
            <span style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/categorias/);"></span> Suspensão </a>

          <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/suspensao-amortecedor-torre-completa">Amortecedor torre completa</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/suspensao-bomba-direcao-hidraulica">Bomba direçao hidraulica</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/suspensao-caixa-de-direcao">Caixa de direçao</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/suspensao-eixo-traseiro">Eixo traseiro</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/suspensao-mola-traseira">Mola traseira</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="list-cat">
          <a href="/tapecaria">
            <span style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/categorias/);"></span> Tapeçaria </a>

          <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/tapecaria-fechadura-da-porta">Fechadura da porta</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/tapecaria-forro-de-portas">Forro de portas</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/tapecaria-jogo-de-bancos">Jogo de bancos</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/tapecaria-quebra-sol">Quebra sol</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="list-cat">
          <a href="/transmissao">
            <span style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/categorias/);"></span> Transmissao </a>

          <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/transmissao-cambio">Cambio</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/transmissao-cardan">Cardan</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/transmissao-diferencial">Diferencial</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/transmissao-semi-eixo">Semi eixo </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="list-cat">
          <a href="/vidros">
            <span style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/categorias/);"></span> Vidros </a>

          <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/vidros-maquina-de-vidro-eletrica">Maquina de vidro eletrica</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/vidros-maquina-de-vidro-manuel">Maquina de vidro manuel</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/vidros-parabrisas">Parabrisas</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/vidros-retrovisores">Retrovisores</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/vidros-vidros-da-porta">Vidros da porta</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Felipe mesmo que fizesse isso você não acha que ficaria meio esquisito o menu ficar crescendo sua height? e empurrando todo o conteúdo pra baixo? Provavelmente iria sobrar um espaço vazio com a cor do seu menu e ficaria meio nada ver.. Porque não pensa em um scroll para o menu?

Comment: É esquisito sim. Mas é solicitação do cliente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header nav { height: auto; }
```

Isso resolveria, ele iria acompanhar todo conteúdo.